# Show online buddy list issue using the ios xmpp Framework

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am building an iPhone application using the XMPP Framework.
I have an issue in the code bellow:

```
NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
    if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) {
        if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {
            [self._chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"server.net"]];
        } else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {
            [self._chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"server.net"]];
        }
   }
```

Suppose that i have created 2 jabber accounts, ichat@server.net and iPhone@server.net. When i launch my application with the iPhone account, i can't see no one is connected. when i remove this line:

```
if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername])
```

i can see two rows with iphone@server.net (my account) one the online buddies table view.
In Debug mode, when i checked the presenceFromUser variable, each time it's containing MY login not login for other buddies online.

Can you help me to fix this please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what was causing this problem.
Indeed, i miss configured the project when creating it, to be more precise I have something wrong when i configured libxml. Right now, it working correctly with the same code.

PS: I think that the XMPP iOS Framework is not still stable, so I think that I will change chat technology within the application.

Comment: How the server connection is madde?