# How to fetch online buddies using xmpp in ios?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to `XMPP` protocol to make a chat application. I am going through many links or tutorials and doing all the setups. I am registering all the users on local host using `XMPP`. When i am testing demo from simulator and device, i am getting buddy list empty. So i am not able to load all buddy list.

How can i use online buddy method and get its response?

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or provide me the appropriate link that tells how to work with `XMPP`?

I am following this link [link 1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-interface-setup--mobile-7188)

I found an answer from this link :[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444321/show-online-buddy-list-issue-using-the-ios-xmpp-framework),
but it is not working,

Comment: helo friends,can i see online friends only on server or local host?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which XMPP server you are using. 
If it is Ejabberd than You can use this XML for getting the all registered users from your server:

```
<iq to='localhost' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/></iq>
```

Please follow the link: [how to get list of registered users](https://www.ejabberd.im/node/3420)